# Accessing Vuex data within dynamic _id.vue page - Vue/Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I want to access my user details stored in the state when visiting a dynamic (_id.vue) page. I have set the id of the page like this after using the link to the page:

```
data() {
    return {
      selectedTutor: null,
      id: this.$route.params.id,
    }
  },
```

But now I need to define the selectedTutor by searching the id within the data in the vuex state. I was trying to do something like this:

```
 created() {
    this.selectedTutor = this.$store.state.tutors.find((tutor) => tutor.id === this.id)
  },
```

But everything stays undefined. So when id equals to the id within the object, that object needs to be set as selectedTutor so I can access all the necessary data to be displayed on the page.

[Here you can see the Vuex state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f0KZ.png)

**EDIT**

**_id.vue page**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <section>
      <div>
        <h3>
          {{ id }}
        </h3>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'TutorPage',
  /* eslint-disable vue/require-prop-types */
  layout: 'app',
  props: ['id'],
  middleware: 'auth',
  data() {
    return {
      selectedTutor: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['tutors']),
  },

  created() {
    this.selectedTutor = this.$store.state.tutors.find(
      (tutor) => tutor.id === this.id
    )
  },
}
</script>
```

**MainResult Page**

```
<base-grid>
      <ul id="tutors" class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6">
        <tutor-item
          v-for="tutor in tutors"
          :id="tutor.id"
          :key="tutor.id"
          :name="tutor.attributes.name"
          :rate="student.hourlyRate"
          :subject="student.subject"
          :description="student.biography"
          :profile-image="student.imageUrl"
          :image-alt="student.imageAlt"
          :age="student.age"
          :rating="student.rating"
          :total-reviews="student.reviewCount"
          class="overflow-hidden bg-white border rounded-lg shadow-md"
        >
        </tutor-item>
      </ul>
    </base-grid>
```

**Tutor Item (the resultcard)**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <li>
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="w-2/3">
          <img
            class="flex-shrink-0 object-cover w-full h-64 mx-auto bg-gray-200"
            :src="profileImage"
            :alt="imageAlt"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="p-6">
          <div
            class="text-xs font-semibold leading-snug tracking-wide text-gray-500 uppercase"
          >
            {{ subject }} &bull; {{ age }} jaar
          </div>
          <NuxtLink :to="'/tutors/' + id">
            <h4 class="text-lg font-semibold leading-5 tracking-wide">
              {{ name }}
            </h4>
          </NuxtLink>
          <div class="mt-2">
            {{ rate }}€

            <span class="text-sm text-gray-600">per uur</span>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-2">
            <span class="font-semibold text-light-blue-800"
              >{{ rating }}/5 sterren</span
            >
            <span class="text-sm text-gray-600 truncate">
              (na {{ totalReviews }} reviews)
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-2">{{ description }}</div>
          <div>
            <div class="mt-4 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-600">
              <span>MA</span>
              <span
                class="inline-block leading-7 text-center text-gray-100 bg-yellow-400 bg-opacity-50 w-7 h-7 rounded-xl"
                >DI</span
              >
              <span>WO</span>
              <span
                class="inline-block leading-7 text-center text-gray-100 bg-yellow-400 bg-opacity-50 w-7 h-7 rounded-xl"
                >DO</span
              >
              <span
                class="inline-block leading-7 text-center text-gray-100 bg-yellow-400 bg-opacity-50 w-7 h-7 rounded-xl"
                >VR</span
              >
              <span>ZA</span>
              <span>ZO</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  /* eslint-disable vue/require-prop-types */

  name: 'TutorItem',
  props: [
    'id',
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
    'name',
    'rate',
    'subject',
    'age',
    'rating',
    'totalReviews',
    'description',
    'profileImage',
    'imageAlt',
  ],
  computed: {
    fullName() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
    },
    tutorsDetailsLink() {
      return this.$route.path + '/' + this.id
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

**EDIT**

Whoops, what a mistake. It was returning the id as a string but I needed a number. This is why it returned undefined. It is solved now! Thanks

Comment: What is the output of logging in `created`:   `this.id` and `this.$store.state.tutors`.  When is the state set?  Show the entire component if possible

Comment: I edited my question with the three componentns. The main page with the resultgrid and inside of that the resultcard which I also posted. Sending props to the resultcard component. The state is set after entering the search query on the main page. When console.logging this.id/this.$route/this.$store.state.tutors gives all undefined.. When I change the created() line to: this.selectedTutor = this.$store.state.tutors.find((tutor) => tutor) it will set selectedTutor (first in the array) so it has something to do with the id

Comment: Ok, I am sorry. The id was expecting a number, and this.$route.params.id returned a string so I needed to convert this. How stupid..